# How to handle exceptions in resolve: clause of $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, routes, route-provider

Suppose a user needs to navigate from list page /people to detail page /person_detail?Id=12 by clicking a hyperlink pointing to a person detail page. Meanwhile another user deleted the person object with id=12.

This will cause a failure to resolve person information in "resolve:" clause or $routeProvider. As a result the URL will change to /person_detail?Id=12 but the browser will still display the list page.

I bet this is a typical problem with AngularJS. The URL needs to change in order to invoke "resolve:", but when "resolve" fails, browser ends up with incorrect URL. Is there a good generic way to handle it?

Here is the code to illustrate the problem

```
$routeProvider.when('/people', { //called for list page
 controller: ListController,
   templateUrl: "/List.html",
}).when('/person_detail', { //called for detail page
 controller: DetailController,
 templateUrl: "/Detail.html",
 resolve: {
   return CallAjax($route.current.params.Id); //suppose this function failed???
 }
})
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return a promise in the resolve? the promise would have the .catch clause to handle the error.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: How should I handle the error and will it revert my URL back to /people?

Comment: Please look at this link : http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved . It explains nicely how to add promises in resolve

Comment: That was useful. Thanks a lot!

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, cur, prev, rejection) {
// you could look at rejection and do something depending on the status code. 
$location.path('/error').replace()

Comment: If my answer is right, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

As for the resolve property, you can set an object map which contains a promise. You can use the catch clause in the promise to handle any fatal errors.

Alternatively you can listen to $routeChangeError event. This is broadcasted if any of the resolve promises are rejected.

The following link nicely explains how deal with resolve.

http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved

Comment: `$routeChangeError` option is great!